# How to position contents according to zoom level?

Tags: html, css

I see this website:

http://www.uppbroadgatepark.com/

I like it. When I zoom in the navigation adjusts, and if I zoomed to >200% a new button called 'Menu' appears, which groups all the navigation links together when clicked.

I want to know how is this possible? Is it pure CSS or JS included? I tried using percentages for scaling but it does not position as cleanly as the website mentioned.

Comment: This is called responsive design, if you resize your browser the same thing will happen. Just Google the term 'responsive design' and you'll find lots of useful articles about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [**Cross Browser Zoom and Pixel Ratio Detector**](https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom)

> **Code**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   var zoom = detectZoom.zoom();
   var device = detectZoom.device();
   alert("zoom: "+zoom +" , device:" +device);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/1opqzxo5/1/)

Comment: I was reading some responsive designs. And was thinking along the lines of listing all of the @media widths and styling accordingly.

So, if I have a iPhone 4, 320 x 480. Can go CODE: (@)media screen and (max-device-width: 640px){ nav ul { min-width: 320px; } ?

PS: nav ul is my menu navigation.

Comment: Ok, This article may be useful to you. [Building A Better Responsive Website](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/05/building-a-better-responsive-website/)

Comment: Thanks for the article, it's quite informative. I'll use this website: http://cssmatter.com/blog/css-media-queries/ for a list of media queries.

I was practicing on my mobile and desktop, I just did a simple background color change on my handheld device and it's different than when I test it on my desktop! I think I know what to do to make the giant button appear when user uses a handheld device. Again, thanks for the article and your device/zoom detection will help me on a more accurate testing! :)